# IOS 7 status bar strange behaviour

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios7

Im having a really really weird problem with IOS 7 status bar.

I am adapting a IOS 6 APP to IOS 7, so i´m creating a custom header view and adding some height when running on IOS 7.

**This is from my Iphone 4 device with IOS 7**

[image: IPhone 4 device]

**And this is the Iphone 4 IOS 7 simulator**

[image: Iphone 4 simulator]

**Exactly same app, same code, same IOS version.**

I cant understand why its showing a IOS 6 style status bar, but its even more strange when i look at the simulator.

I can notice that its adding the status bar height on both, but on the device its starting form behind status bar...

Can someone give some hint?

Comment: Just to make sure, you have not messed with your project settings of SDK, right? You are compiling with base SDK of 7.0?

Comment: Yea im compiling with SDK 7.0 Xcode 5.0.1, but your right it looks exactly when compiling with SDK 6.0, i have another app compiled with it, can it be bugged?.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to Leo Natan for pointing me to test the proyect SDK, i may be just a bug of xcode.

I´ve change to sdk 6.0 compile and run, change to sdk 7.0 again, compiled and fixed...

Thanks to all anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Try to set translucent property set to NO. I have been with the same issues recently.

```
self.navigationController.navigationBar.translucent = NO;
```

And in your plist file add view controller-based status bar appearance and make it NO

Comment: doesnt do nothing, even setting yes or no, nothing changes.